# Sencha Touch : Open View on List Click

Tags: list, extjs

I have a list, I want to open a View/Panel when "itemtap" event is fired (i.e. when a list item is selected). How to do it? Shall I use NestedList and getDetailCard() for it?

Thanks

EDIT : I think I should use CardLayout for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your situation.

If the new content you are trying to display is supposed to be replacing content on the screen, that yes using the CardLayout is the best option. This would be akin to emulating something like the UISplitViewController in the iOS world, where you have a list on the left and a main view on the right in which additional content is slid onto the screen based on actions to the right list.

So, on response to 'itemtap' events in the list you would do a 'setActiveItem' call to the panel that has a layout of card layout, and a series of children panels.  You could also lazily create the panels in response to the list actions and add them on the event.

Comment: Yes, that is what I did. How to add animation to the panels? I mean a sliding animation?

Comment: There is two ways: 1. is through the property 'cardSwitchAnimation' on the panel, which can be something like 'slide', 'fade' 2. The other way is specifying it when calling the function to switch the cards, on the parent, 'setActiveItem(newpanel, 'slide')' for example.   Be sure to consult to documentation for all the options